# Improve a function to extract year, month and date of week

Tags: r, function, data.table, dplyr

I'd like to write a wrap function where I can reduce the steps to extract year, month and day of the week, so I don't have to repeartly put down the date variable name. Also if I need extra seasonal variable or some other time object line, I can just add extra line in the function.

The line by line way is

```
library(lubridate)
yr = year(travel_date)
mth = months(travel_date)
day = weekdays(travel_date))
```

I can chain them through a `dplyr` way:

```
cat <- cat %>% mutate(yr = year(travel_date), 
                      mth = months(travel_date),
                      day = weekdays(travel_date))
```

The `data.table` way:

```
cat[, yr := year(travel_date)][, mnth := months(travel_date)][, dayweek := weekdays(travel_date)]
```

My wrap function idea is that I only need to put down the dataframe name and the variable name once. But it's not working.

```
time_spin <- function(x, y) {
  x[, yr := year(y)][,mth := months(y)][,day := weekdays(y)]
}
```

Any suggestion I can improve this? I can take a wrap function through `dplyr` or `data.table`.

dput

```
cat <- structure(list(id = 1:6, 
                      travel_date = structure(c(16107L, 17266L, 16834L, 17953L, 17953L, 17953L), 
                                              class = c("IDate", "Date"))), 
                 row.names = c(NA, -6L), 
                 class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr` you can write the function as :

```
time_spin <- function(x, y) {
  x %>% mutate(yr = year(.data[[y]]), 
                 mth = months(.data[[y]]),
                 day = weekdays(.data[[y]]))
}

time_spin(cat, 'travel_date')

#   id travel_date   yr      mth       day
#1:  1  2014-02-06 2014 February  Thursday
#2:  2  2017-04-10 2017    April    Monday
#3:  3  2016-02-03 2016 February Wednesday
#4:  4  2019-02-26 2019 February   Tuesday
#5:  5  2019-02-26 2019 February   Tuesday
#6:  6  2019-02-26 2019 February   Tuesday
```

Comment: Thanks @Ronak Shah! It works. Out of curiosity, how to understand the part `.data[[y]]`? Anywhere I can look this up?

Comment: We use that construct when we pass  column name as string in function. You can read more about it at https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Comment: Thanks again! This is really helpful.